# Secured Servlet using @EmbeddedIdentityStoreDefinition, works with TomEE Plume, not in WildFly20

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, java-ee-8

I am trying to implement **Java EE 8 security** with very simple example codes.
This is the *servlet* that is secured:

```
@WebServlet(name = "/InitiateRead", urlPatterns = {"/initread.do"})
@DeclareRoles({"user","admin","guest"})
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"user","admin"}))
@BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(realmName="secured-basic")
@EmbeddedIdentityStoreDefinition({
    @Credentials(callerName = "user",  password = "password",   groups = {"user" }),
    @Credentials(callerName = "admin", password = "admin",      groups = {"admin"}),
    @Credentials(callerName = "guest", password = "guest",      groups = {"guest" })}
)
public class InitiateRead extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
           ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("inside read initiator servlet.");
  }
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
           ServletException, IOException {
      doGet(request,response);
  }
```

This is the implementation of **HttpAuthenticationMechanism**:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ContentAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism{
    private Map<String,String> users;
    private Map<String,Set<String>> roles;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        users= new HashMap<>();roles= new HashMap<>();      
        users.put("admin", "admin");users.put("user", "password");users.put("guest", "guest");      
        roles.put("admin", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("admin")));
        roles.put("user", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("user")));
        roles.put("guest", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("guest")));      
    }
    @Override
    public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpMessageContext httpMessageContext) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username= request.getParameter("username");
        String password= request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("username:"+username+" password:"+password);
        if(username!=null && password != null) {
            if(users.containsKey(username)){
                if(users.get(username).equals(password)) {
                    return httpMessageContext.notifyContainerAboutLogin(username,roles.get(username));
                }
            }
            return httpMessageContext.responseUnauthorized();                       
        }
        return httpMessageContext.doNothing();
    }   
}
```

A simple `index.jsp` submits the username and password to the servlet.
Here's the trimmed `POM.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>javax</groupId> 
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId> 
            <version>8.0</version> 
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.glassfish.soteria</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise</artifactId>  
            <version>1.0.1</version>  
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>secured</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

now in **TomEE Plume**, upon providing correct credential and submitting the form in hits the servlet, prints the `System.out.println()` message in the console. But in **WildFly 20**,  even after providing the login credetial and submitting the jsp form, it shows ***Forbidden*** . The same code behaves differently in two cases.
Please guide me, I think I am missing a very basic point here.

Comment: A very basic point that you probably missed is that TomEE does not implement Jakarta Security, and therefor completely ignores @BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition etc.

TomEE is working on Jakarta Security, see https://github.com/apache/tomee/pull/658 but it's not there yet.

Comment: Then I guess, @EmbeddedIdentityStoreDefinition wont work with WildFly, as it's not part of the API.

Comment: WildFly happens to use Soteria, but indeed, @EmbeddedIdentityStoreDefinition is not part of the API. But does it matter here? As the example code (`ContentAuthenticationMechanism`) doesn't use an identity store.

The problem might be that WildFly still requires security to be activated. See e.g. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/development_guide/jakarta_ee_security_api

Comment: I tried again following <https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/development_guide/jakarta_ee_security_api> , *Enabling Jakarta EE Security API for Web Applications* which has the same effect of placing the **jboss-web.xml** in the **WEB-INF** folder, i.e. `AmbiguousResolutionException`. One for the built-in `org.glassfish.soteria.cdi.CdiProducer` and the other for the custom `HttpAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` implementation(`Managed Bean [class com.sec.service.ContentAuthenticationMechanism] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]`).

Comment: Now, I guess JASPI kicks in fine,because when the `ContentAuthenticationMechanism` is annotated with `@Alterantive`, the container prompts for login credentials and reaches the servlet upon providing correct credentials.What should be the approach here so that The custom implementation of `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` would use the `@EmbeddedIdentityStore`?

Comment: You `@Inject` the `IdentityStoreHandler` and then call out to it. See for instance https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/j-javaee8-security-api-3/

Comment: This time modified the HAM implementation :
` @Inject
 private IdentityStoreHandler i; 

 @Override
 public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(...){
  String u= request.getParameter("username");
  String p= request.getParameter("password");
  UsernamePasswordCredential upc = new UsernamePasswordCredential(u, p);
   CredentialValidationResult c = i.validate(upc);
   if(c.getStatus() == Status.VALID) {
    return httpMessageContext.notifyContainerAboutLogin(c);
   }
   else {
    return responseUnauthorized();
   }
  }   
  return doNothing();
 } 
}`

Comment: But that results the same, the HttpAuthenticationMechanism Implementation does not interceopt at all. May be I am missing something in some server configuration? @ArjanTijms

Comment: Perhaps best to start with the examples here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/soteria/tree/1.0.1/test

These are all fully working mini-apps (wars). Start from the working example, then modify them piece by piece towards your own code. Test them in between. As soon as it stops working, you are close to what may go wrong.

Comment: thanks for the goldmine.

Answer (score 0):

With **JASPIC** enabled by placing `jboss-web.xml`,any `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` implementation causes `AmbiguousResolutionException` by WildFly.`soteria`'s implementation collides with that of the custom one.This can be bypassed by implementing `IdentityStore` and overriding the `validate()` for credential validation purpose.Without `jboss-web.xml`, JASPIC won't kick in.Upon hitting the secured servlet it will always return HTTP - 403.Even if the custom `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` is in place,it will not be able to intercept,it would be `403` without **jboss-web.xml**.In this modified implementation, the validation mechanism is delegated to `soteria`'s own `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` implementation.Only this servlet is used here to test run `@EmbeddedIdentityStoreDefinition`.

```
@WebServlet(name = "/InitiateRead", urlPatterns = {"/initread.do"})    
@DeclareRoles({"user","admin","guest"})
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"user","admin"}))
@BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(realmName="security-realm")
@EmbeddedIdentityStoreDefinition({
    @Credentials(callerName = "user",  password = "password123",    groups = {"user" }),
    @Credentials(callerName = "admin", password = "admin123",       groups = {"admin"}),
    @Credentials(callerName = "guest", password = "guest123",       groups = {"guest"}) 
    })
public class InitiateRead extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Inject
  private Logger logger;
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      logger.log(Level.INFO,"inside  read initiator servlet's .doPost() .");
  }
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      doGet(request,response);
  }  
}
```

The test codes https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/soteria/tree/1.0.1/test given by @ArjanTijms proved to be the one-stop solution for beginners like me to grasp the core concepts of **Jakarta EE**'s **Security API**.